# length restriction for the sql variable on sqlsrv_query?

Tags: php, sql-server

Is there any known length restriction for the sql variable on sqlsrv_query?
I have an application that sends a block of commands do SQL SERVER (insert into..., insert into..., etc).
It works fine on Linux (mssql) but on Windows (sqlsrv) the last instructions are ignored.
The sql command where the last instructions are lost has 4900 lines.

```
$qry_str = "";
for () {
    $qry = "INSERT INTO tbl
                (field1,
                 field2,
                 etc)
            VALUES
                ('$val1',
                 '$val2',
                 etc)";
    //echo "<pre>$qry</pre>";
    $qry_str .= "$qry;\n";
}
```

Comment: just to be clear, you're asking about the length of the query itself, and not the result set coming back, correct?

Comment: exactly, the length of the query itself

Comment: A single command with 4900 lines???

Comment: not sure if this is an exact duplicate or not, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1869810/697370) has your answer and links to docs

Comment: It's not a single command, is a group of commands, as shown above.
We prefer to send it in a single string to SQL server to make sure the batch is executed only if there is no error on any of the queries. If sent individually to SQL server one mispeled query will be ignored, but the rest will be executed. It works fine with mssql on linux but is not working with sqlsrv

Answer (score 0):

On `sqlsrv_query` a sql string larger then 65536 is truncated to 65536 characters. Try to use `mssql_query` or write your query to file and execute it from sqlcmd tool. This may help you [Does Microsoft sqlsrv driver for PHP has limitation on query string length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22300274/does-microsoft-sqlsrv-driver-for-php-has-limitation-on-query-string-length)

Comment: As far as I know mssql_query is not available on 5.3+ windows versions

Comment: Quite right. So you can do it with `sqlcmd`, the link shows example how to do it.

Comment: I'm looking for some workaround php only. For now I'm splitting large commands (GT 65536) on my class to exec blocks of code instead of processing the entire command. tks anyway for the suggestion.